# Version 2:Help finding the probability that $Ax^2 + Bx + C$ has real roots?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that $A, B,$ and $C$ are independent random variables, each being uniformly distributed over $(0,1)$. What is the probability that $AX^2 + BX + C$ has real roots?

I am given a hint that if $X$ ~ uniform $(0, 1)$, then $-\ln(X)$ is exponential. The sum of two (or more) independent exponential random variables is gamma...

How does this hint help answer this question?

Thanks a lot

Comment: we need $b^2-4ac$ to be greater than 0.Now take log on both sides you get $ln(b)$ on one side and sum of two ln on other side

Comment: could you write it out..."take log on both sides.....two ln on other side" was not so clear to me

Comment: Calculate the @g76989b integral.

Comment: I am told the following: $$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_{\min\{1, \sqrt{4ac}\}}^1 1 \;\text{d}b\,\text{d}c\,\text{d}
&a= \int_0^1 \int_0^{\min\{1, 1/4a\}}\int_{\sqrt{4ac}}^1  1\;\text{d}b\,\text{d}c\,\text{d}a\\
&= \int_0^{1/4} \int_0^1 \int_{\sqrt{4ac}}^1 1\;\text{d}b\,\text{d}c\,\text{d}a + \int_{1/4}^1 \int_0^{1/4a}\int_{\sqrt{4ac}}^1 1\;\text{d}b\,\text{d}c\,\text{d}a
\end{align}$$  why the middle integrate from 0 to min{1, 1/4a} from the second integral.>.where does 1/4a come from? why the min{...} does not go to the front integral? why they break up into last step like this

Answer (score 1):

Taking Logarithm yields

$2*ln(b)=ln(4)+ln(a)+ln(c)$. On the LHS we have an exponential random variable on the RHS we have sum of two exponential random variables which is Gamma.

On the right it is $\Gamma(2,1)$ on the left side it is $\Gamma(1,1)$.

Comment: could you go on a little further...as I still do not see how to approach it?

Comment: first of all, you have to move the equation into $-ln(4) - ln(a) - ln(c) = -2ln(b)$...then my question why $\Gamma(2,1)$ and $\Gamma(1,1)$?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf in the pdf of $\Gamma$ put 1 and 1 for the 2 parameters it will become exponential

Comment: you lost me again...could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf pdf of Gamma distribution is $1/(\Gamma(k)\theta^k)$$x^{k-1}$$e^{-x/\theta}$. Put k=1 and $\theta$ =1

Comment: I got put k=1 and $\theta =1$ into gamma distribution will give us exponential...how does $\Gamma(2,1)$ and $\Gamma(1,1)$ help here? What are the roles for them?

Comment: By the way, what does the two coordinates in $\Gamma(2,1)$ is associated with since for Gamma pdf, we only have $\Gamma(\text [ $one$ $variable$])$?